# Swapping scanf to fgets and random symbols

Tags: c, printf, scanf, fgets

I set a challenge to create a simple crime reporting system. I originally used scanf to input data but have transfered a few over the fgets which has causes multiple sections of printf to bunch without asking for an input. Also the report section at the end of the code prints random symbols and I can't figure out how to remove them.

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main ()
{

int  incident_day, incident_month, incident_year, incident_hour,     incident_minute, dd, mm, yy;
long long int contact_number, wit_contact_number[12];
char safe_place, CRS_qu, medical_qu, incident_address, incident_address_house_no[10], incident_address_street[10], incident_address_postcode[10], assailant_qu;
char assailant_name[20], assailant_address[40], wit_qu, wit_name[20], weapon_description[50], armed_qu[3];
char first_name[20], surname[20];


start:
printf(" Are you in a safe place? (Y/N)\n");
scanf(" %[^\n]s", &safe_place);

while (safe_place == 'N' || safe_place == 'n')
    {
        printf(" Please contact the police Service immediatly on 999\n");
        break;
    }


printf(" This Crime Reporting System is for victims on assuault only, Are you a victim on assault? (Y/N)\n");
scanf(" %[^\n]s", &CRS_qu);

while (CRS_qu == 'N' || CRS_qu == 'n')
    {
        printf(" Please select the appropriate Crime Reporting System related to the crime you want to report\n");
        goto start;
    }

printf(" Have you had any medical treatment for any injurys sustained during the incident? (Y/N)\n");
scanf(" %[^\n]s", &medical_qu);

while (medical_qu == 'N' || medical_qu == 'n')
    {
        printf(" Please contact the Ambulance Service on 999 and get imediate medical attention\n");
        break;
    }

printf(" Please enter the date of the incident? (DD/MM/YY)\n");
scanf("%d/%d/%d", &incident_day, &incident_month, &incident_year);


start2:
printf(" Please enter an approximate time of the incident? Format 24:00\n");
scanf("%d:%d", &incident_hour, &incident_minute);

if (incident_hour <00 || incident_hour >23 || incident_minute <00 || incident_minute >59)
{

    printf(" Please enter a valid time in a 24:00 format\n");
    goto start2;
}


printf(" Do you know the address of the incident? (Y/N)\n");
scanf(" %[^\n]s", &incident_address);

while ( incident_address == 'Y'|| incident_address == 'y')
    {
        printf(" Please enter the House No.?\n");
        fgets(incident_address_house_no, 10, stdin);

        printf(" Please enter the Street Name?\n");
        fgets(incident_address_street, 10,  stdin);

        printf(" Please enter the Postcode?\n");
        fgets(incident_address_postcode, 10, stdin);
        break;
    }

printf(" Do you know the assailant? (Y/N)\n");
scanf(" %[^\n]s", &assailant_qu);

while ( assailant_qu == 'Y' || assailant_qu == 'y')
    {
        printf(" Enter the assailants name?\n");
        fgets(assailant_name, 20, stdin);

        printf(" Enter the assailants address?\n");
        fgets(assailant_address, 40, stdin);
        break;
    }
while ( assailant_qu == 'N' || assailant_qu == 'n')
    {
        printf(" A detective will be incontact to get a description of the assailant\n");
        break;
    }

printf("Were there any witnesses to the incident? (Y/N)\n");
scanf(" %[^\n]s", &wit_qu);

while ( wit_qu == 'Y' || wit_qu == 'y')
{
    printf(" Enter the witnesses name?\n");
    fgets(wit_name, 20, stdin);

    printf(" Enter the witnesses contact number?\n");
    fgets(wit_contact_number, 12, stdin);
    break;
}

printf(" Was the assailant armed? (Y/N)\n");
fgets(armed_qu, 3, stdin);

while ( *armed_qu == 'Y' || armed_qu == 'y')
{
    printf(" Please describe what the assailant was armed with?\n");
    fgets(weapon_description, 50, stdin);
    break;
}

printf(" \nPlease enter yours details when prompted\n");

printf(" \nPlease enter your First Name\n");
scanf("%s", first_name);

printf(" \nPlease enter your Surname\n");
scanf("%s", surname);


printf(" \nPlease enter yours Date of Birth, format DD/MM/YYYY\n");
scanf("%d/%d/%d", &dd,&mm,&yy);

          if(yy>=1900 && yy<=2018)
    {
        //check month
        if(mm>=1 && mm<=12)
        {
        //check days
        if((dd>=1 && dd<=31) && (mm==1 || mm==3 || mm==5 || mm==7 || mm==8 || mm==10 || mm==12))
            printf("Date is valid\n");
        else if ((dd>=1 && dd<=30) && (mm==4 || mm==6 || mm==9 || mm==11))
            printf("date is valid\n");
        else if ((dd>=1 && dd<=28) && (mm==2))
            printf("Date is valid.\n");
        else if ((dd==29 && mm==2 && (yy%400==0 || yy%4==0 && yy%100!=0)))
            printf("Date is valid.\n");
        else
            printf("Date is invalid.\n");

    }
}

mo:
printf("\nEnter Contact Number +44");
while ( !scanf("%lli",&contact_number))
{
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("\n Invalid Contact Number:\n\n");
    printf(" Enter Contact Number Again : ");
}
if (contact_number < 1000000000 || contact_number > 9999999999)
{
    printf("\n Please Enter only 10 digits.....\n");
    goto mo;
}


printf(" Victims Details\n");
printf(" Full Name              : %s %s \n", first_name, surname);
printf(" DOB                    : %d/%d/%d \n", dd,mm,yy);
printf(" Contact Number         : +44%lld \n", contact_number);
printf(" Witness Details\n");
printf(" Full Name              : %s\n", wit_name);
printf(" Contact Number         : +44%lln\n", wit_contact_number);
printf(" Assailant Details\n");
printf(" Full Name              : %s\n", assailant_name);
printf(" Address                : %s\n", assailant_address);
printf(" Incident Details\n");
printf(" Date of Incident       : %d/%d/%d \n", incident_day,incident_month, incident_year);
printf(" Time of Incident       : %d:%d\n", incident_hour, incident_minute);
printf(" Street No. of Incident : %s\n", incident_address_house_no);
printf(" Address of Incident    : %s\n", incident_address_street);
printf(" Postcode of Incident   : %s\n", incident_address_postcode); 
printf(" Was the Assailant Armed: %s\n", armed_qu);
printf(" Description of Weapon  : %s\n", weapon_description);



return 0;

}
```

Comment: First of all, don't use `goto` and labels instead of loops.

Comment: Using both `fgets()` and `scanf()` in the same program leads to troubles.  Best to only use `fgets()`.

Comment: Secondly, you use the `%[` `scanf` format *wrong*. It's no `s` after it, that makes `scanf` want to match an actual `s` character in the input.

Comment: And *another* problem with your use of `scanf` and the `%[` format, is that `%[` is used to read ***null-terminated strings***, and you provide single characters as arguments. That means `scanf` will write (at least) *two* characters to the memory starting with the character you provide. That writing out of bounds leads to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OP's code has various types of errors

#### Unneeded `s` in `scanf(" %[^\n]s"`

The `s` serves no purpose

```
// scanf(" %[^\n]s", &safe_place);
scanf(" %[^\n]", &safe_place);
```

#### Mixing `scanf()` with `fgets()`

Use of `scanf(" %[^\n]"...` consumes leading whitespace including prior `'\n'` yet leaves any `'\n'` after the text input in `stdin`.  `fgets()` reads up to **and including** the `'\n'`. A `fgets()` right after `scanf(" %[^\n]"...` will only read the prior input's left-over `'\n'`.

#### Lack of width limitation

Buffer may readily overflow.

```
char first_name[20];
// scanf("%s", first_name);
scanf("%19s", first_name);
```

#### Saving a *string* into a single `char`

`safe_place` needs a size of at least 2, one for the `'Y'` or `'N'` and the terminating *null character*.

```
// char safe_place;
char safe_place[10];
printf(" Are you in a safe place? (Y/N)\n");
// scanf(" %[^\n]s", &safe_place);
scanf(" %9[^\n]", &safe_place);
```

#### Scant error checking

Should unexpected data get entered, code does not verify for correct input, nor does it consume the errant input.

```
// scanf("%d/%d/%d", &incident_day, &incident_month, &incident_year)
if (scanf("%d/%d/%d", &incident_day, &incident_month, &incident_year) != 3) {
  Handle_Bad_Input_Somehow();
}
```

---

Below is some alternative code to show reading a line and then using it.

```
int get_line(const char *prompt, char *dest, size_t size) {
  printf("%s", prompt);
  fflush(stdout);
  if (fgets(dest, size, stdin) == NULL) {
    dest[0] = '\0';
    return 0;
  }
  dest[strcspn(dest, "\n")] = '\0';  // Lop off potential trailing '\n'
  return 1;
}

int main(void) {
  char safe_place[10];
  get_line(" Are you in a safe place? (Y/N)\n", safe_place, sizeof safe_place);
  if (safe_place[0] == 'N' || safe_place[0] == 'n') {
    printf(" Please contact the police Service immediately on 999\n");
  }

  char date[20];
  int  incident_day, incident_month, incident_year;
  do {
    get_line(" Please enter the date of the incident? (DD/MM/YY)\n", date, sizeof date);
  } while (sscanf(date, "%d/%d/%d", &incident_day, &incident_month, &incident_year) != 3);

  char incident_address_house_no[20];
  get_line(" Please enter the House No.?\n", incident_address_house_no, 
      sizeof incident_address_house_no);

  printf(" Date of Incident       : %d/%d/%d \n", incident_day, incident_month,
      incident_year);
  printf(" Street No. of Incident : %s\n", incident_address_house_no);
  return 0;
}
```